# PHP Extract multiple images from MySQL database field

Tags: php, mysql

I'm pulling in data from a csv file and inserting it into a MySQL database. The images are being inserted into a field called `picturerefs`, example shown below, and are stored on a seperate website.

```
http://images.somesite.co.uk/foldername/image28177_1b.jpg,
http://images.somesite.co.uk/foldername/image28177_2b.jpg,
http://images.somesite.co.uk/foldername/image28177_3b.jpg,
http://images.somesite.co.uk/foldername/image28177_4b.jpg,
http://images.somesite.co.uk/foldername/image28177_5b.jpg,
http://images.somesite.co.uk/foldername/image28177_6b.jpg,
http://images.somesite.co.uk/foldername/image28177_7b.jpg,
http://images.somesite.co.uk/foldername/image28177_8b.jpg,
http://images.somesite.co.uk/foldername/image28177_9b.jpg
```

How would I go about extracting these images in order to display them on the front-end of the website in a thumbnail gallery? Any help greatly appreciated, S.

Comment: If you could insert them, you should be able to retrieve them as well. Creating a gallery is a different issue altogether.

Comment: Yeah, what part of the operation are you having difficulty with? Querying the data, separating the file names, or building the gallery?

Comment: can you post the database table you are using.

Comment: Having trouble seperating the filenames...

Comment: use php's pathinfo() for extracting filename. have a look at this function http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do .

```
$file_names = explode("," , $row['picturerefs']);
echo $file_names[0];
echo $file_names[1];
```

.. so on

If there are 7 file names in that column, then you will have a $file_names array from 0 to 6.

Assuming you are using $row inside the loop after getting the data from the DB.